# On an equation that involves the number-of-divisors function and the formula for a sequence of figurate numbers

Tags: divisibility, elementary-functions, divisor-counting-function

In this post we try to relate a sequence from [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/) and a sequence that solves an equation that involves the number-of-divisors function $\sigma_0(n)=\sum_{1\leq d\mid n}1$.

I don't know if my conjecture is easy to get (other conjectures can be done when one thinks in similar equations for other figurate numbers, for example the heptagonal pyramidal numbers in relation to *A111398*).

**Conjecture.** *The integers* $y\geq 1$ *and* $x\geq 1$ *satisfy*
$$\sigma_0(y)=\frac{x}{3}(2x^2+1)\tag{1}$$
*if and only if* $y$ *belongs to the sequence A162947 from the OEIS, that are the integers* $y$ *such that*
$$\prod_{1\leq d\mid y}d=y^3.$$

The expression in the RHS of $(1)$ is the formula for octahedral numbers, Wikipedia has the article with title [*Octahedral number.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_number)

> **Question.** Can you to prove or provide me hints to prove the conjecture? **Many thanks.**

**Edited.** Now I see that the $\Leftarrow$ is easy, since from exercise 10 of Chapter 2 of Tom M. Apostol, *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*, Springer (1976), it is possible to deduce that each term $y$ of *A162947* has six divisors whenever $y>1$, and from here $x=2$ gives the solution of the equation $(1)$.

I don't know if it is easy to get (at least a part of the conjecture should be easy to get), since this sequence of integers has a very special spatial configuration. If you know it from the literature, feel free to answer as a reference request and I try to search and read the solution from the literature.

### References:

[1] John Horton Conway and Richard K. Guy, *The Book of Numbers*, Springer-Verlag (1996).

Comment: As additional information if you want to explore other sequences, the encyclopedia Wolfram MathWorld shows a table of figurate numbers from the article *Figurate Number*.

Comment: I know the formula for the product of positive divisors of an integer $\prod_{1\leq d\mid n}d$, from exercise 10 of Chapter 2 of Tom M. Apostol, *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*, Springer (1976). From which it is possible to deduce that each term of *A162947* has six divisors whenever $y>1$.

Comment: For any positive integer $n$, there is always a number with exactly $n$ divisors, e.g. $p^{n-1}$ for any prime $p$.

Comment: If some user wants to explore similar equations involving multiplicative functions and figurate numbers that he/she feel free to do it. Many thanks again for the patience and help of users of MSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=3$, then $\frac{x}{3}(2x^2+1)=\frac{3}{3}(2(3)^2+1)=2(9)+1=18+1=19$, so $y=2^{18}$ (which has exactly $19$ divisors) is a counterexample to the conjecture.

I do not know the *smallest* counterexample, however.

Comment: Many thanks for your excellent answer (to be honest I did not know if my question was a good question, but your answer improves the post a lot).